# Search a word in a text file and return its frequency

Tags: java

How to search for a particular word in a text file containing texts of words and         return its frequency or occurrences ?

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is a fair common piece of homework. I am sure if you search around you will find plenty of solutions.

Comment: i have tried using a treemap but it returns the entire words in the text and display it as an array of words and individual word's frequency. now i would like to the program to prompt the user to enter a desired word and returns the word and the particular word's frequency only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a Scanner:

```
String text = "Question : how to search for a particular word in a " +
        "text file containing texts of words and return its " +
        "frequency or occurrences ?";

String word = "a";

int totalCount = 0;
int wordCount = 0;
Scanner s = new Scanner(text);
while (s.hasNext()) {
    totalCount++;
    if (s.next().equals(word)) wordCount++;
}

System.out.println("Word count:  " + wordCount);
System.out.println("Total count: " + totalCount);
System.out.printf("Frequency:   %.2f", (double) wordCount / totalCount);
```

Output:

```
Word count:  2
Total count: 24
Frequency:   0.08
```

Comment: hi thanks for your example..i am using your concept and implementing in my code. thanks. I now trying to figure out how to make the string to process a text file rather than only few string of words..

Comment: Instead of passing `text` to the scanner constructor, you could just as well pass a file. [See the api docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: hi, thanks. i figure it out. thank you very much for your advice. i appreciate it. :)

Comment: hi, sorry to bother you. Some of the words that occur only once in the text but the program return it as 0 frequency. Can advice?

Comment: oh sorry, i mean the word count is 0. Even though i look myself in the text there is one word, but the program return 0 in the word count.

Comment: no worries, i already figure it out..thanks for your help. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Read These

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Write_a_Java_program_to_find_occurrences_of_given_word_in_a_text

http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010006/

http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread181889.html

Answer (score 0):

- Read each line in the file. See [Tutorial | Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)
- You can use [string.contains](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to check if the line contains the word you are looking for
- increment an int counter if the word is found